# Codeigniter multiple join query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('user_profile.user_id,story.story_id,display_name,story_title,synopsis,genre_name,tag_name,content_warning_name');
$this->db->from('story');
$this->db->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = story.user_id');
$this->db->join('story_genre', 'story_genre.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->join('story_tag', 'story_tag.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->join('story_content_warning', 'story_content_warning.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->where('story.story_id', $story_id);
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
$count = 0;
foreach($query as $row){
$story['author_id'] = $row->user_id;
$story['author_name'] = $row->display_name;
$story['story_title'] = $row->story_title;
$story['synopsis'] = $row->synopsis;
$story['genre'][$count] = $row->genre_name;
$story['tags'][$count] = $row->tag_name;
$count++;}
```

Above code works, problem is that it repeats itself 4 times(around the number of joins, coincidence? i think not).

Genre would output:**Action Romance Fantasy Action Romance Fantasy Action Romance Fantasy Action Romance Fantasy**

Clarification: The duplicates came from the query itself looping x amount of joined tables. I don't know if i did something wrong writing my query but it works and shows no errors so.

4 joined tables = print_r($query) will print out $query 4 times.

Am i overdoing it? Should i only join tables that have 1 row of values only and not ones that are multiple/arrayed(result).

To prevent the duplicates. I could set a limit variable as count of query result.

but the simplest one is to change the array key to a name.

```
$story['genre'][$row->genre_name] = $row->genre_name;
$story['tags'][$row->tag_name] = $row->tag_name;
```

The above code prevents duplicates even though the query ran 4 times(due to the 4 joins, the duplicate entries just overwrites itself, same as the other columns selected)

Comment: I think you have add a distinct in the select query to avoid duplicates. I have no background with codeigniter

Comment: Its the same. Am i overdoing it? or am i correct in joining them?

I can think of ways to prevent the duplicates. I just don't know if i am on the right track.

Comment: You are joining it correctly, but it depends on the data. Can you share the data from source table? I can explain better

Comment: My story_genre table consists of 3 columns, story_genre_id(AI PK) story_id(FK) and genre_name.

There are duplicates of genre_name but not the story_id. There could be 4 'fantasy' genre names but not of the same story_id. same applies to story_tag and content warning

Comment: Say you are joining two tables A and B based on pkey, A has one row (with pkey = 1) and B has three rows(with pkey =1 ). Now your result will have three rows. If you put a distinct, you can avoid duplicates

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The duplicates did not come from multiple tables. It came from the same table.

I checked with print_r($query) after the $db->get()->result();

It showed me multiple instances of $query->result();

For example above: i joined 4 tables, when i printed query, it printed 4 instances of the query.

So when i looped with foreach, it looped all over again, 4 times.

Comment: try this $this->db->select('user_profile.user_id, distinct story.story_id,display_name,story_title,synopsis,genre_name,tag_name,content_warning_name');

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are mainly joining on user id

```
$this->db->select('user_profile.user_id,distinct story.story_id,display_name,story_title,synopsis,genre_name,tag_name,content_warning_name');
$this->db->from('story');
$this->db->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = story.user_id');
$this->db->join('story_genre', 'story_genre.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->join('story_tag', 'story_tag.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->join('story_content_warning', 'story_content_warning.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->where('story.story_id', $story_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
if(!$query->num_rows())
        return false;
foreach($query->result() as $key => $story){
   $story['author_id'] = $row->user_id;
   $story['author_name'] = $row->display_name;
   $story['story_title'] = $row->story_title;
   $story['synopsis'] = $row->synopsis;
   $story['genre'][$key] = $row->genre_name;
   $story['tags'][$key] = $row->tag_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split your queries - because it doesn't make much sense to combine `1:n` and `n:m` relations, just because you want to do it with one query only...
(although i'm not sure where `story_content_warning` belongs - if it is a `1:n` relation - you can join it in the first query)

for instance the following should show what i mean

```
$this->db
    ->select('user_profile.user_id,story.story_id,display_name,story_title,synopsis');
    ->from('story');
    ->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = story.user_id');
    ->where('story.story_id', $story_id);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
    $objStory = $query->row();

    $objStory->genre = [];
    $objStroy->tags = [];


    $query = $this->db
        ->select('genre_name')
        ->from('story_genre')
        ->where('story_id', $objStory->story_id)
        ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $objStory->genre = $query->result();
    }

    $query = $this->db
        ->select('tag_name')
        ->from('story_tag')
        ->where('story_id', $objStory->story_id)
        ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $objStory->tags = $query->result();
    }

}
```